# How to deploy a maven web project using Wildfly to Heroku?

Tags: maven, heroku, wildfly, java-ee-7

I've built a Java EE 7 web app on Wildfly 10.

I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku, but I can't make the application work.
All I could do, so far, was to get Wildfly to work, but it seems to be running without my application.

I pushed the application using git:

```
git push heroku master
```

And it is running the unpack goal.

The Procfile:

```
web: target/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=$PORT -b 0.0.0.0
```

The pom.xml

```
<!-- Commented to keep it simple -->
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>target/wildfly-${version.wildfly}/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your ear/war into your wildfly deployment folder. To do that you need a separate plugin or something that will do that.

I want to try this too, so I will for example use this plugin under ear pom:

```
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>../pathto/deployments</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```

You might need to use something else for a war.

To test it works just try compiling it and watch if your app is in the deployment folder.